# R neuralnet using a starting formula to add weights to colums

Tags: r, neural-network, formula

I'm using R with the Neuralnet package to create a neural network.
I was wondering if it is possible to attach starting weight's / a starting formula to the Neural network.

for example:
the dataset (dataset is much larger just showing a sample):

```
Outcome (Y) Temperature (x)
  55         10,5
  52         11,4
  46         8,1
  45         7,6
```

I want to add a formula (before it starts with the calculations)

formula: **temperature change with 1 degrees changes outcome with 2**

Comment: `startweights` argument will let you set starting weights (though they will change during learning). I'm not sure what you mean by "add a formula before it starts with the calculations," do you mean the hidden layer connections(?) or applying a data transformation to the input data?

Comment: with startweigts how can you select a specific column, if i have multiple in a dataframe

Comment: I would suggest that you read a few introductory articles on neural nets (in R) (https://www.r-bloggers.com/fitting-a-neural-network-in-r-neuralnet-package/, https://medium.com/@brscntyz/neural-network-in-r-e275302b6e44, https://datascienceplus.com/neuralnet-train-and-test-neural-networks-using-r/). The whole point of a neural network is that you do not specify the coefficients but that the neural net learns the optimal coefficients from the data.

Comment: That is True, I just wanted to experiment with it, thanks for the links